# Enable and disable ng-bind-html according to a $ctrl value in angular component

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, ng-bind-html

I'm using angualr component(1.5) .In My code i need to disable of using ng-bind-html directive if $ctrl.buttonTextStyle variable has no value.

```
<div>
<button id="saveBtn" class="pe-btn--btn_large pe-btn__primary" type="submit" ng-style="$ctrl.buttonStyle">
    <span class="btnText" ng-bind-html="$ctrl.buttonTextStyle">Save</span>
    <div class="loading" style="display:none" ng-style="$ctrl.dotStyle">
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
</button>
<span id="saveError" class="condition-one" style='display:none' ng-style="$ctrl.errorStyle">Changes could not be saved</span>
</div>
```

This will cause to reduce normal button length(Save Button).

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? if it's simply changing the look, you should use ng-class.

Comment: Actually this code is working fine. But initially $ctrl.buttonTextStyle variable has no value. There for button styles are not working properly. I have set the content to button in the controller. But button's length is smaller.

Comment: if that's the case, then try using the ng-cloak attribute on your span tag.

Comment: I tried. Then the binding is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if condition

```
<span class="btnText" ng-if="$ctrl.buttonTextStyle" ng-bind-html="$ctrl.buttonTextStyle">Save</span>
```